# Show $D_6$ isomorphic to $S_3$ considering an action.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\{1,g,h,h^2,gh,gh^2\}$ where $g^2=h^3=1$ and $gh$ and $gh^2$ has order $2$. The question is : show that $G$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ using the action of $G$ on $\{g\in G\mid o(g)=2\}$ by conjugacy.

I don't really understand what it mean, could you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

The conjugacy action of $G$ on itself realizes all possibile permutations of the three elements of order 2, so it gives a surjective homomorphism of $G$ onto $S_3$. Since the two groups have the same order, this must be an isomorphism.